# MySQL find result that is substring of a query string

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a query string like `This is a computer`. And I have some words in database like `computer`, `This`, `machine`.

I want to find the words which are the substrings of the query string. For the example above, I will get `This` and `computer`.

How to write the mysql statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below using [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE INSTR('This is a computer', word) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
words
FROM
table_with_words
WHERE 'This is a computer' LIKE CONCAT('%', words, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many words in table, mb, preferable will be using of such query:

```
SELECT word
FROM table_with_words
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(word, REPLACE('This is a computer', ' ', ',')) != 0
```